# jquery show/hide multiple elements based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm using jQuery to filter a list of elements that are on a page using a HTML select which has a list of client IDS. The HTML elements on the page have a data attribute of `data-client`. I'm using jquery to filter out the ones that do not match. However the code I have is hiding all elements. My code is below;

```
<select class="form-control placeholder" id="filterSelect" name="clients">
  <option value="14">Client 14</option>
  <option value="45">Client 45</option>
  <option value="48">Client 48</option>
</select>

<div class="filterable">
  <div class="filter" data-client="14">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 14</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter" data-client="45">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 45</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter" data-client="48">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 48</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter" data-client="14">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 14</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter" data-client="48">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 48</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jquery is as follows;

```
$('#filterSelect').change(function() {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this).val();
  var filter = $('.filter');

  if (filter.attr('data-client') != optionSelected) {
    filter.hide();
  }

});
```

I also have a jsfiddle;

https://jsfiddle.net/to53jbe5/

Hope someone can help me filter out the ones that do not match the selected value of the select.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Use `[data-client="YOUR_VALUE"]` to select elements with attributes. `$('.filter[data-client="' + optionSelected + '"]')` will select all the elements having class as `filter` and attribute `data-client` as *selected value.*[[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)]

`.change()` will trigger `change` event initially to filter selected value elements

Try this:

```js
$('#filterSelect').change(function() {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this).val();
  $('.filter').hide();
  $('.filter[data-client="' + optionSelected + '"]').show();
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control placeholder" id="filterSelect" name="clients">
  <option value="14">Client 14</option>
  <option value="45">Client 45</option>
  <option value="48">Client 48</option>
</select>

<div class="filterable">
  <div class="filter" data-client="14">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 14</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter" data-client="45">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 45</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter" data-client="48">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 48</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter" data-client="14">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 14</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="filter" data-client="48">
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <h4>Client 48</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/to53jbe5/1/)

Comment: I want the same answer but using jQuery ajax